# Unable to log-in to phpMyAdmin after switching to php-fpm

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, phpmyadmin

I have a CentOS 7 server, running Apache 2.4. I use phpMyAdmin on it to connect to remote MySQL database instances (on Rackspace). MySQL is not running on the server. The phpMyAdmin config.inc.php has details of the remote Rackspace hostname. When PHP is configured to use the Apache 2.0 Handler, that is fine, ie when my /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf contains the following command:

SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

Switching that to php-fpm, ie:

SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"

prevents me being able to log-in to phpMyAdmin (401 response).

I am unclear why switching the PHP handler would affect phpMyAdmin in this way. Server logs show nothing of relevance. How can I use php-fpm without breaking phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as yours after switching to php-fpm and I solved by using 'cookie' auth_type in phpMyAdmin config.inc.php in /etc/phpMyAdmin.

My best guess why it wasn't working in http auth_type is because htpasswd auth is somehow linked to apache user and since when we're running php with php-fpm the user is not apache but php-fpm instead.